# assembly version mismatch when using OpenAIClient

Tags: c#, revit-api

Im trying to get response from openAI by sending prompt in class library, I have downloaded azure.AI.OpenAI package then Im unable to create client but same code is working fine when Im using winforms project template without any error

here is the code:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClient(new Uri("my uri"), new AzureKeyCredential("my key"));

    var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
    {
        DeploymentName = "my deployment name", //This must match the custom deployment name you chose for your model
        Messages =
        {
            new ChatRequestSystemMessage("You are a helpful assistant."),
            new ChatRequestUserMessage("please translate 'BUILDING FINAL DETAILS TO BE CONFIRMED BY A SUPPLIER IN THE NEXT PROJECT PHASE.' to spanish."),
            new ChatRequestAssistantMessage(""),
        },
        MaxTokens = 100
    };

    Response<ChatCompletions> response = client.GetChatCompletions(chatCompletionsOptions);

    Console.WriteLine(response.Value.Choices[0].Message.Content.Split('"')[1]);

    Console.WriteLine();

}
```

tried all versions of azure.ai,.openai

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and explain what the title has to do with the rest of the question?  (What is the actual error message that your are receiving?)

Comment: The likely cause is that some other addin or Revit itself is using another version of `Azure.AI.OpenAI`. Check out this post for how to check which version is getting load and where it is getting loaded from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78177832/15534202

Comment: I answered your identical question in the [Revit API discussion forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/assembly-version-mismatch-when-using-openaiclient/m-p/12650458).